# Remove autorun.inf from pendrive automatically

Tags: vb.net

I've made a simple application to automatically remove `autorun.inf` from pendrive.
My algo is very simple, at an interval the app runs how many drive is there if it gets a Removable disk it tries to delete autorun.inf file.
But i want to optimize it by removing the timer.
How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn’t to clear.  I assume you mean you want your application to run every time a USB drive is inserted?  You should be able to do it using a managementeventwatcher.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher.aspx

This component runs a query you provide on your computers WMI instance.  WMI will detect your USB drive and then your watcher will raise the event.